# Pasar imagen mediante AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

Hola amigos tengo un formulario el cual pasa una serie de valores mediante Ajax y uno de esos valores es una imagen, todos los valores de los inputs se me pasan perfectamente menos la imagen que no consigo guardarla ya que me dice que la variable esta vacía.

HTML

```
<input name="unidadescaja" id="valor1" type="number" placeholder="Unidades por caja"><br/><br/>

<input name="precio" id="valor2" type="number" placeholder="Precio" step=".01"><span> €</span><br/><br/>

<textarea name="descripcion" id="valor3" style="width:70%;height:200px;" ></textarea><br/><br/>

<input type="file"   name="imagen" id="valor4" accept="image/jpeg"><br/><br/>

<input type="button" href="javascript:;" onclick="realizaProcesoAP($('#valor1').val(), $('#valor2').val(), $('#valor3').val(), $('#valor4').val());return false;" value="Registrarse"/>
```

AJAX

```
function realizaProcesoAP(valorCaja1, valorCaja2, valorCaja3, valorCaja4){
    var parametros = {
            "valorCaja1" : valorCaja1,
            "valorCaja2" : valorCaja2,
            "valorCaja3" : valorCaja3,
            "valorCaja4" : valorCaja4,


    };
    $.ajax({
            data:  parametros, //datos que se envian a traves de ajax
            url:   'php/insertarproducto.php', //archivo que recibe la peticion
            type:  'post', //método de envio
            beforeSend: function () {
                    $("#ErroresRegistro").html("Procesando, espere por favor...");
            },
            success:  function (response) { //una vez que el archivo recibe el request lo procesa y lo devuelve
                    $("#ErroresRegistro").html(response);
            }
    });
```

PHP

```
copy($_FILES['valorCaja4' ]['tmp_name'],"images/ImgProductos/".$ID);

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['valorCaja4']['tmp_name'],"images/ImgProductos/".$ID);
```

Comment: Ufff tu código es muy raro, para pasar imágenes usa mejor un `form` que sea `multi-part`. Luego, tu `onclick` puesto *in line*  en el HTML no me convence. Es mejor como ya dije usar un `form` y escuchar los envíos del mismo recogiendo los datos en Javascript, así respetas el principio de separación del código. En tu código PHP tampoco entiendo el sentido que tiene el uso de `copy` y de `move_uploaded_file`.  Te aconsejo que estandarices el código para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Con lo del `onclick` *in line*  me refiero a esto: `onclick="realizaProcesoAP($('#valor1').val(), $('#valor2').val(), $('#valor3').val(), $('#valor4').val());return false;"` Pasar los datos así es horrible, es una mala práctica y podría ser erróneo. Puedes hacer una prueba de consola y verás si tengo razón o no.

Comment: a ver el codigo tal cual pasandolo por php metodo post funciona correctamente con la imagen y todo...

Comment: Como hago para pasar el formulario completo y no por inputs mediante ajax

Comment: David si buscas aquí mismo en Stackoverflow verás múltiples ejemplos que explican cómo hacerlo. Revisa alguno de esos ejemplos y si tienes alguna dificultad nos puedes preguntar y podremos ayudarte.

Comment: yo  lo pasaria a base64 y lo meteria en un campo en la tabla

Comment: @JJMADEO ¿por qué lo harías así? A veces es mejor tener los archivos en directorios que en una tabla.

Comment: facilidad supongo, es comodo

Answer (score 0):

algo que veo que estas enviando es el valor del input en la imagen pero en el caso de las imágenes se debe enviar diferente se recibe con $_FILES este contiene el valor que le ingresaste prueba con:

```
if (isset($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name']) && !empty($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'])) {

}
```

Además cuando estas enviando datos por AJAX no es necesario especificar en metodo POST en el formulario ya que todo lo envías por medio de javascript y para eso se utiliza un objeto llamado [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/Usando_Objetos_FormData) el cual permite compilar un conjunto de pares clave/valor para enviar mediante XMLHttpRequest (AJAX).

Ahora como te comentan los compañeros de la comunidad es sin duda mejor enviarlo no en linea si no mas bien dentro de un script y te dejo un ejemplo algo básico ya que se puede mejorar muchísimo más pero eso te toca a ti hacerlo... solo es cosa de que lo adaptes a tu código:

Formulario:

```
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Registrar Producto</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <h1>Registrar Producto</h1>
                <div id="ErroresRegistro"></div>
                <form id="formulario">
                    <input name="unidadescaja" id="valor1" type="number" placeholder="Unidades por caja"><br/><br/>

                    <input name="precio" id="valor2" type="number" placeholder="Precio" step=".01"><span> €</span><br/><br/>

                    <textarea name="descripcion" id="valor3" style="width:70%;height:200px;" ></textarea><br/><br/>

                    <input type="file" name="imagen" id="valor4" accept="image/jpeg"><br/><br/>

                    <button type="submit" id="guardarRegistro">Registrar</button>

                    <div id="ErroresRegistro"></div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Script.js**

```
$('#guardarRegistro').click(function(e) {
    $("#ErroresRegistro").html('');
    e.preventDefault(); // Detienes la accion por defecto
    var unidades = $('#valor1').val(); // obtienes el valor del input
    var precio = $('#valor2').val(); // obtienes el valor del input
    var descripcion = $('#valor3').val();// obtienes el valor del input
    var imagen = $("#valor4")[0].files[0]; // obtienes el archivo cargado en el input
    console.log("imagen", imagen);
    // Obviamente aqui debes hacer validaciones para que no vengan vacios los campos...
    // que vengan solo los tipos de archivo que quieres almacenar...
    // No puedes permitir que almacenen cualquier puedes hacer que tu sitio sea vulnerable 
    if (unidades == '' || precio == '' || descripcion == '' || imagen == '') {
        $('#ErroresRegistro').html(`<p style="background:red; color:white; margin-top:10px; padding:10px;">Todos los campos son requeridos</p>`);
    } else if (imagen["type"] != "image/jpeg") { 
        $('#ErroresRegistro').html(`<p style="background:red; color:white; margin-top:10px; padding:10px;">Solo se permiten archivos en formato JPG.</p>`);
    } else {
        $('#ErroresRegistro').html('');
        var datos = new FormData(); // https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/Usando_Objetos_FormData
        datos.append('valorCaja1', unidades)
        datos.append('valorCaja2', precio)
        datos.append('valorCaja3', descripcion)
        datos.append('valorCaja4', imagen)
        $.ajax({
            url: "insertarproducto.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: datos,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#ErroresRegistro").html(`<p style="background:orange; color:white; margin-top:10px; padding:10px;">Procesando, espere por favor...</p>`);
            },
            success:  function (response) { //una vez que el archivo recibe el request lo procesa y lo devuelve
                $("#ErroresRegistro").html(response);
            }
        })
    }
})
```

**insertarproducto.php**

```
<?php

// AJAX

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { // Valida que solo se pueda acceder al archivo si es una peticion tipo POST
    if ($_FILES['valorCaja4']['name'] != '' && !empty($_FILES['valorCaja4'])) { // Valida que no venga vacia la imagen...
        // Haz más validaciones lado servidor que sea el formato que vas a aceptar como en el javascript JPG o el que tu desees...
        if ($_FILES['valorCaja4']['type'] != 'image/jpeg') {
            echo '<p style="background:red; color:white; margin-top:10px; padding:10px;">Solo se permiten archivos en formato JPG.</p>';
        } else {
            // Valida los datos des inputs
            // Tú SQL lo mandas aquí de preferencia con PDO
            // Luego de que alamacenes los datos mandas la imagen al directorio
            $id = 1; // esto debe de venir de tu base de datos, lo pongo aqui solo para pruebaimages/ImgProductos/'.$ID
            $nombre_img = 'imagen_producto_' .$id . '.jpg'; 
            // las carpetas deben estar creadas si no es asi te dara un error, si no estan creadas indaga sobre como crear directorios en php.
            // ruta final de la imagen. Esta deberias de guardarla en un campo de tu BD para poderla mostrar en algun otro lugar
            $destino = 'images/ImgProductos/'.$nombre_img; 
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['valorCaja4']['tmp_name'], $destino);
            echo '<p style="background:green; color:white; margin-top:10px; padding:10px;">Se han almacenado los datos</p>';
        }

    }
}
```

Los demás datos vienen en sus variables $_POST

```
$_POST['valorCaja1']
$_POST['valorCaja2']
$_POST['valorCaja3']
```

Saludos.